# AWS SNS in Flutter

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter

I wonder if maybe anyone has worked with aws push notifications with flutter for ios, android and huawei platforms. If so, what plugins have they used?

If you have documentation on this topic, I would appreciate it if you share it.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look this? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/announcing-aws-amplify-flutter-developer-preview/

Answer (score 0):

You can use SNS Mobile Push notification in IOS & Android, but not in < Huawei > as I know !!

Visit this docs to understand more: https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/#Mobile_push_notifications

SNS Mobile Push lets you use Simple Notification Service (SNS) to deliver push notifications to # Apple, Google, Fire OS, and Windows devices, as well as Android devices in China with Baidu Cloud Push # . With push notifications, an installed mobile application can notify its users immediately by popping a notification about an event, without opening the application.

**AWS Amplify for Flutter**
AWS Amplify announces its support for the Flutter framework.

AWS Amplify offers a variety of services such as Authentication, including third party/social media log in, push notifications, storage, GraphQL, Datastore, REST API, Analytics, PubSub, and more.

Visit this article : https://medium.com/flutter-community/aws-amplify-for-flutter-ed7890f75493

Answer (score 0):

AWS amplify do not support notification for flutter.
You can link AWS SNS with your firebase messaging conf and got notification through Firebase notification.

Very good post / tutorial : https://medium.com/iiitians-network/flutter-push-notifications-using-aws-sns-dac464c1edf0